# require(): Failed opening required php file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, xampp, require, autoloader

Recently, I formated my whole computer, and installed Windows 7 64-bit. Before doing that I saved all of my files on an external hard drive. One of the things I backed up was a PHP script which uses AWS DynamoDB Services.

Before I formated my computer, everything went perfect. After I formated it, I installed on it XAMPP, Visual Studio Code, and PHP 7.1.1 through Microsoft WebPI.

Currently when I'm trying to run my PHP script I get this error on my screen:

> **Warning**: require(/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **D:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\htdocs\public_html\file.php** on line **7**
>
> **Fatal error**: require(): Failed opening required '/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php'(include_path='D:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\php\PEAR') in **D:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\public_html\file.php** on line **7**

I'm calling the autoloader this way:

```
require '/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
```

I'm trying to understand if I forgot to install another thing, or if it's something related to the system (I had Windows 10 before)...

Could you please help me figure it out? I'm pretty new to this topic of PHP...

Comment: what kind of path is `/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php` on windows?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU The file is in `D:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\public_html\` and `aws-autoloader.php` is in `D:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\public_html\zip\aws\aws-autoloader.php`

Comment: the you should o like this: `require __DIR__ .  '/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php';`

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU It solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  specify the entire path, like this: `require __DIR__ .  '/zip/aws/aws-autoloader.php';`